# How to check if one record is attached to another?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have defined a many-to-many relationship between `Student` and `Seminar` models. How can I find out if **one particular student** is attending **one particular seminar**? Non-working example of what I want to achieve is illustrated below:

```
$seminar->students()->contains($student->id);
```

The following error is shown when using the above code snippet:

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::contain()'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try instead:

```
$seminar->students->contains($student->id);
```

Presuming `$student` contains an instance of the `Student` model you can simplify it further and just use:

```
$seminar->students->contains($student);
```

When you add parentheses you're using the Laravel query builder, and you never completed the query. To do it in the manner you had originally you would need:

```
$seminar->students()->get()->contains($student->id);
```

This method could be useful if you wanted to add constraints when fetching your students.

But generally you can omit the parentheses and a Collection will be returned, allowing you to use methods like `contains`.

This has the additional benefit of not re-querying the database once the relationship is loaded, so will generally be a far more efficient means of fetching relationships.

If you haven't already loaded the students and want a database efficient method of checking you could instead use:

```
$seminar->students()->where('students.id', $student->id)->exists();
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Wouldn't that introduce an unnecessary load on the DB? Since it retrieves all of the students of the given `$seminar` from the database and only after that it checks the array with `contains()`

Comment: Yes. In which case you can't use `contains` as it's a Collection method. You'd instead need something like: `$seminar->students()->exists($student -> id);`

Comment: Thank you, the `exists()` method was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @MattMcDonald I have a simular issue too, do you think I can somehow use `$seminar->students()->exists($student->id);` inside an if statement? I never used many to many before so I'm having quite a little trouble with it.

Comment: Not sure if this has changed in laravel, but `exists()` doesn't take any parameters as of 5.7. The last code example will ignore the parameter and make a DB call to check if any students exist in the seminar, not just a specific one.

Answer (score 6):

In your case the exception is you are calling 'contains()' function (which is for Laravel Collection) on 'Query Builder'. It should be

```
$seminar->students->get()->contains($student->id);
```

but this is inefficient since this will retrieve all the students of the seminar.

so instead,

```
$seminar->students()->wherePivot('student_id', $student->id)->exists();
```

this method will check in the intermediate table of many to many relationship for particular seminar-student pair, and will return whether exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is wrong. `$seminar->students()->exists($student->id)` does not check if the relationship exists. It only checks if the student exists. The student could belong to any seminar and it would still return true.

The correct way to check if a relationship exists without fetching records from the database would be:

`$seminar->students()->whereId($student->id)->exists()`

Comment: `$seminar->students()->exists($student->id)` and `$seminar->students->exists($student->id)` do very different things - note there are no `()` in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check using query

```php
$seminar->students()->whereKey($student->getKey())->exists();
```

Check after query (angry), can have memory problems if you have multiple attachments

```php
$seminar->students->contains($student->getKey());
// or
$seminar->students()->get()->contains($student->getKey());
```